# C While Loop Issues

Tags: c, while-loop, crash

I am fairly new at coding in C. I am trying to get the project below to run but it says my program has stopped working after I enter the third input. I am not confident that my choice of using a while loop with all or booleans is the correct choice of approaching this. I almost feel like there should be an if/else statement added to the program somewhere.

I have been provided a flow chart for the project that is basically along these lines:

> Get input values for inv1-4
>
> While code !=-1
>
> if code is !=1 proceed with loop and get input values for amounts
>   bought/sold
>
> else print inv1-4

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    int inv1;
    int inv2;
    int inv3;
    int inv4;
    int amount_purchased;
    int amount_sold;

    printf("Please provide beginning inventory amounts in cases between 1 and 4.\n\n");
    printf("Enter the number of inventory for Piels (ID number 1): ");
    scanf("%d", &inv1);

    printf("\nEnter the number of inventory for Coors (ID number 2): ");
    scanf("%d", &inv2);

    printf("\nEnter the number of inventory for Bud (ID number 3): ");
    scanf("%d", &inv3);

    printf("\nEnter the number of inventory for Iron City (ID number 4): ");
    scanf("%d", &
          inv4);


    while (inv1 != -1 && inv2 != -1 && inv3 != -1 && inv4 != -1) {
            printf("\nEnter the number of cases of Piels (ID 1) purchased and sold this week.\n");
            printf("Amount purchased: \n");
            scanf("%d", &amount_purchased);
            printf("Amount sold: \n");
            scanf("%d", &amount_sold);
            inv1 = inv1 + amount_purchased - amount_sold;

            printf("\nEnter the number of cases of Coors (ID 2) purchased and sold this week.\n");
            printf("Amount purchased: \n");
            scanf("%d", &amount_purchased);
            printf("Amount sold: \n");
            scanf("%d", &amount_sold);
            inv2 = inv2 + amount_purchased - amount_sold;

            printf("\nEnter the number of cases of Bud (ID 3)purchased and sold this week.\n");
            printf("Amount purchased: \n");
            scanf("%d", &amount_purchased);
            printf("Amount sold: \n");
            scanf("%d", &amount_sold);
            inv3 = inv3 + amount_purchased - amount_sold;

            printf("\nEnter the number of cases of Iron City (ID 4) purchased and sold this week.\n");
            printf("Amount purchased: \n");
            scanf("%d", &amount_purchased);
            printf("Amount sold: \n");
            scanf("%d", &amount_sold);
            inv4 = inv4 + amount_purchased - amount_sold;



    }

    printf("Ending inventory is as follows.\n\n");

    printf("Piels (ID Number 1): %d \n", inv1);
    printf("Coors (ID Number 2): %d \n", inv2);
    printf("Bud (ID Number 3): %d \n", inv3);
    printf("Iron City (ID Number 4): %d \n", inv4);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Syntax is `scanf("%d", &inv1);`

Comment: Also, the `while (inv1 || inv2 || inv3 || inv4 != -1)` is very odd. What is the intended effect of this?

Comment: `scanf("%d ", inv1);`?  Enable all your compiler warnings, and pay attention to them.

Comment: Same applies to *every* `scanf` statement. You have to pass the address of the variable to be input. (Except if you should input a string using `%s` format just pass the array identifier, because is decays to its address).

Comment: I just noticed that you have an unconditional `break` at the end of the loop. If you are leaving the loop anyway in the first iteration, why do you do the loop in the first place? Or did you forget to add some `if(condition)` for the `break`?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem with this

```
while (inv1 || inv2 || inv3 || inv4 != -1)
```

is that what you wrote is not what you expect. `(inv1 || inv2 || inv3 || inv4 != -1)` evaluates to true when
`inv1` is not 0, **or** `inv2` is not 0, **or** `inv3` is not 0, **or** `inv4`
is not -1. What you probably want is if either one of these variables
is -1, the loop must end. The correct condition would be in that case:

```
while(inv2 != -1 && inv2 != -1 && inv3 != -1 && inv4 != -1)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that in boolean algebra `a && b` is equivalent to `!a || !b`. And `a || b`
is equivalent to `!a && !b`.

Also your `scanf`s are wrong as many people wrote in the comments. You have to
pass a pointer to `int`, not an `int`. So instead of

```
scanf("%d", amount_sold);
```

it should be

```
scanf("%d", &amount_sold);
```

and this applies to all your `scanf` calls, otherwise it's undefined behaviour
and the result of undefined behaviour is undefined.

**edit**

I just noticed that you have an unconditional `break` at the end of the loop. If
you are leaving the loop anyway in the first iteration, why do you do the loop
in the first place? Or did you forget to add some `if(condition)` for the
`break`?

Comment: This does appear to be the correct logic I was looking to achieve. Thank you for clearing that up. My first input statement takes two inputs. Is there something that might be causing this? I am trying to follow a flow chart provided for the project and am not really sure why a while loop is being requested for this scenario.

Comment: @DylanAlbert I don't know what you mean by two inputs, I don't see anywhere in your code where you have two inputs in the same `scanf`. But apart of the wrong logic, your `scanf` calls are wrong and yield undefined behaviour, and that means that anything can happen, from a crash to declaring war to Noth Korea.

Comment: @DylanAlbert until you correct the coding errors, the behaviour is irrelevant, since the program contains *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 1):

You have some basic syntax problems like

```
scanf("%d", &inv1)
```

instead of

```
scanf("%d", inv1)
```

The while loop syntax is also wrong.

```
while(inv2 != -1 && inv2 != -1 && inv3 != -1 && inv4 != -1)
```

instead of

```
while (inv1 || inv2 || inv3 || inv4 != -1)
```

And another logic issue. The while loop will run once. Because you have written the "break" statement at the end of the loop. So there is no need for any loop at all. Just write without loop

```
printf("\nEnter the number of cases of Piels (ID 1) purchased and sold this week.\n");
        printf("Amount purchased: \n");
        scanf("%d", &amount_purchased);
        printf("Amount sold: \n");
        scanf("%d", &amount_sold);
        inv1 = inv1 + amount_purchased - amount_sold;

        printf("\nEnter the number of cases of Coors (ID 2) purchased and sold this week.\n");
        printf("Amount purchased: \n");
        scanf("%d", &amount_purchased);
        printf("Amount sold: \n");
        scanf("%d", &amount_sold);
        inv2 = inv2 + amount_purchased - amount_sold;

        printf("\nEnter the number of cases of Bud (ID 3)purchased and sold this week.\n");
        printf("Amount purchased: \n");
        scanf("%d", &amount_purchased);
        printf("Amount sold: \n");
        scanf("%d", &amount_sold);
        inv3 = inv3 + amount_purchased - amount_sold;

        printf("\nEnter the number of cases of Iron City (ID 4) purchased and sold this week.\n");
        printf("Amount purchased: \n");
        scanf("%d", &amount_purchased);
        printf("Amount sold: \n");
        scanf("%d", &amount_sold);
        inv4 = inv4 + amount_purchased - amount_sold;
```

It will work the same if it is what you meant to do.

Comment: You have repeated the same mistakes.

Comment: At lest fix the `scanf` calls